# Apache POI Formulaerror for specific column

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a spreadsheet that is processed by Apache POI that throws errors up if a certain column is used.

Upon updating the spreadsheet the total amount of used columns went from 163 to 291 and the error started to appear. The process of updating the spreadsheet involved insert groups of mainly 25 columns int he middle of the sheet. After spending several hours trying to locate the problematic column I have determined that column GH is what causes issues when modified. I've tried inserting new columns to both sides, filling column GH with formula, text, integers, changing the formatting, the cell decoration and if it is changed at all it throws up the same error.

Strangely enough I don't think it's the amount of columns that is causing the issue because id I enter anything into the end column the sheet still processes fine as long as GH is left untouched.

As it stands column GH has no data within it and is only formatted to have thick borders and a fill colour.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown error type: -60
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FormulaError.forInt(FormulaError.java:131)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.setCellErrorValue(XSSFCell.java:611)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFormulaEvaluator.setCellValue(XSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:203)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(XSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:147)
```

The error itself relates to a formula error, but it occurs even if no formula is entered into column GH and even if any of the formula in the following columns are left untouched.

Comment: Why are you evaluating the cell as a formula, if by your own comment `no formula is entered into column GH` ?

Comment: Because there is meant to be formula in that column. The same formula that is used thousands of times else where in the spreadsheet.
If it adds anything, I have no control over the server or how it processes the spreadsheets.

Comment: Are you sure your formula is valid? Only it does look like the evaluation is triggering a problem due to the formula

Comment: I am pretty sure. It's identical to majority of the formula used else where besides the cells it's referencing. I know it's not the cell it's referencing because the same cell is referenced else where with no issues. And like I've already said, the error is thrown whether the cell is empty or not.